# Async method not execute sometimes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have WebApi controller with async method Post:

```
public class WebApiController : ApiController
{
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            string json = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TModel>(json);
            var newEntity = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(model);
            var newEntityVersion = Mapper.Map<TEntityVersion>(model);
            var result = await CurrentRepository.AddAsync(newEntity, newEntityVersion);

            return CreateResponse(result, "DefaultApiPost");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Post in " + ControllerName, e);

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
        }
    }
}
```

AddAsync method looks like :

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity, TEntityVersion version)
{
 await DatabaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
 return entity;
}
```

When I call Post method using HttpClient I can enter AddAsync method :

```
client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

But when I call Post method using WebApi controller explicit I can not enter AddAsync method, just jump over it :/ :

```
 var product = FakeProduct();

        var newEntity = Mapper.Map<ProductEntity>(product);
        var newEntityVersion = Mapper.Map<ProductVersionEntity>(product);

        productRepository.AddAsync(newEntity, newEntityVersion).Returns(Task.FromResult<ProductEntity>(newEntity));


        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Product);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:8888/api/Product/")
          {
              Content = new StringContent(content),
          };

        var webApiController = FakeWebApiControllerWithPostRoute();

        var result = await webApiController.Post(request);

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Created, result.StatusCode);
```

Any idea why this method is not executed ?

Comment: Can you provide the method context where each method is called?

Comment: PostAsync I call to add entity from ui, Post is called in nunit test. It it enough?

Comment: Who has written the Unit test? You? Does it use any mocking framework or MS Fakes ?

Comment: I'm assuming you "can not enter" means you can't debug it. Is the debugger ever reaching the `Post` action of the `WebApiController`? If it is, the problem is that you can't Step Into the `AddAsync` method, right?

Comment: I edit code. Yes I reach Post webApi method but debugger avoid AddAsync method :/ I know this, because after this method me entity should be change, and I set breakpoint here.

Comment: Is it just skipping it? maybe an exception has been thrown? You can try settings on all CLR Exceptions.

Comment: @netmajor It looks like your `productRepository` is a fake, so why do you expect it to call the real `AddAsync()`?